# Skipping provider screen in FirebaseUI

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to find a way to skip provider options screen in FirebaseUI.

I just need phone authentication and there is no need to show user provider options.

Is there a way to take user directly to phone authentication screen?

Here is my code on viewcontroller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //createGradientLayer()
    checkLoggedIn()
}

func checkLoggedIn() {
    Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
        if user != nil {
            // User is signed in.
        } else {
            // No user is signed in.
            self.login()
        }
    }
}

func login() {
    let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()
    authUI?.delegate = self as? FUIAuthDelegate
    let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [
        FUIPhoneAuth(authUI:FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()!),
        ]
    authUI?.providers = providers
    FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()?.isSignInWithEmailHidden = true
    let authViewController = authUI?.authViewController()
    self.present(authViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith user: User?, error: Error?) {
    if error != nil {
        //Problem signing in
        login()
    }else {
        //User is in! Here is where we code after signing in

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to the [FirebaseAuthUI documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/tree/master/FirebaseAuthUI), you cannot customize the flow. (See the section on custom email/password screens)

Comment: Thank you!. Do you know how to customize (put a logo) on providers option screen?

Comment: Why yes I do! You need to make a subclass of authPickerViewController. Then in viewDidAppear, you can add the desired image and constraints, etc. The link to GitHub should help, but also check this out: http://blog.thatjenperson.com/2017/03/fuiauth-adventures-in-cancelling.html?m=1

Comment: This answer is wrong, you are able to skip that screen using the method     [provider signInWithPresentingViewController:self phoneNumber:nil];

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there. After `FUIAuthProvider` initialization start Phone Auth flow directly:

```
FUIPhoneAuth *provider = self.authUI.providers.firstObject;
[provider signInWithPresentingViewController:self];
```

Here is [sample code](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/blob/master/samples/objc/FirebaseUI-demo-objc/Samples/Auth/FUIAuthViewController.m#L196-L197).

In order to add logo to Welcome screen subclass `FUIAuthPickerViewController` and implement `FUIAuthDelegate` delegate method:

```
func authPickerViewController(forAuthUI authUI: FUIAuth) -> FUIAuthPickerViewController
```

Here is [one more sample](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/blob/master/samples/swift/FirebaseUI-demo-swift/Samples/Auth/FUICustomAuthUIDelegate.swift#L38-L40) for this.

Comment: Use `provider.signIn(withPresenting: self)` can do the trick to skip provider screen. But FUIAuthDelegate method `authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith user: User?, error: Error?) ` fail to get user info after sign in flow completed. Need to use `addStateDidChangeListener` of auth to monitor the user info while signed in.

Comment: Be careful, this method is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

Let's supose that you have a view controller with a button to start the phone validation. This is the code that should be included in the button (obj-c)

```
- (IBAction)btnPhoneValidation:(id)sender {
    FUIAuth *authUI = [FUIAuth defaultAuthUI];
    authUI.delegate = self;

    //The following array may contain diferente options for validate the user (with Facebook, with google, e-mail...), in this case we only need the phone method 
    NSArray<id<FUIAuthProvider>> * providers = @[[[FUIPhoneAuth alloc]initWithAuthUI:[FUIAuth defaultAuthUI]]];
    authUI.providers = providers;

    //You can present the screen asking for the user number with the following method.
    FUIPhoneAuth *provider = authUI.providers.firstObject;
    [provider signInWithPresentingViewController:self phoneNumber:nil];

    //This is the default way to present several options.
//    UINavigationController *authViewController = [authUI authViewController];
//    [self presentViewController:authViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

The same process but with e-mail authentication, replacing the provider type:

```
NSArray<id<FUIAuthProvider>> * providers = @[[[FUIEmailAuth alloc]init]];
    authUI.providers = providers;

FUIEmailAuth *provider = authUI.providers.firstObject;
[provider signInWithPresentingViewController:self email:nil];
```

Comment: There are several examples with presenting the phone auth process, but how do you custom present email auth?

Comment: I edit the answer, in the following link you can find a complete guide: https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-ios/auth/readme.md/